# Laravel 419 Error > Element UI File Upload Vue Js Component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I am using Element UI's **Vue Js** file upload component in **Laravel**. The component has an action attribute that takes the request url.

After browsing and selecting the file I am getting a **419 (unknown status) error** which I think has to do with token authrization.

My question is how do I implement this **csrf token authrization** in this **Element UI component**

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <el-container>
    <side-nav></side-nav>
    <el-main>
      <el-upload
        id="file"
        name="file"
        ref="file"
        class="upload-demo"
        drag
        action="http://request/url"
        :on-preview="handlePreview"
        :on-remove="handleRemove"
        :file-list="fileList"
        multiple>
        <i class="el-icon-upload"></i>
        <div class="el-upload__text">Drop file here or <em>click to upload</em></div>
        <div class="el-upload__tip" slot="tip">jpg/png files with a size less than 500kb</div>
      </el-upload>
    </el-main>
  </el-container>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        fileList: [],
      };
    },
    methods: {
      handleRemove(file, fileList) {
        console.log(file, fileList);
      },
      handlePreview(file) {
        console.log(file);
      },
      handleExceed(files, fileList) {
        this.$message.warning(`The limit is 3, you selected ${files.length} files this time, add up to ${files.length + fileList.length} totally`);
      },
      beforeRemove(file, fileList) {
        return this.$confirm(`确定移除 ${ file.name }？`);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And Here is the error:

[image: 419 Unknown Status]
I appreciate any feedback you may have!

Comment: where is your axios.post code?

Comment: I'm kind of new to this. Is that required to make the request? What is the action="http://request/url" then?  That is where I'm putting the post request right now

Comment: follow this link https://serversideup.net/uploading-files-vuejs-axios/

Comment: That was actually exactly the link I followed for a first design, and it works so I may have to go back to it. I just like the UI and feedback the Element UI component gives, but not sure how to complete a successful post request with it

Answer (score 1):

You should add csrf token data to **headers** attribute;

https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload#attributes

component;

```js
<el-upload :headers="{ 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf }"></el-upload>
```

```js
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['csrf']
    }
</script>
```

blade;

```php
<your-component csrf="{{ csrf_token() }}"></your-component>
```

I hope this would help you!

Answer (score 0):

On the upload component, the action attribute should point to the url that handles the request.

`action="http://request/url"`

Make sure you have implemented it and have the correct route as the value of this attribute

Answer (score 0):

Grab the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie and add it to the headers in the upload property of component like this:

```js
data() {
  return {
    headers: {
      'X-XSRF-TOKEN': this.$cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
    }
  }
}
```

You can use any other method to obtain the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie. As long as the value of the cookie gets send as a header prop named `X-XSRF-TOKEN` it will work. This example makes use of the [vue-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies) library.